# Increasing each element of a tensor by the predecessor in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

I'm new to *tensorflow 2.0*, and haven't done much except designing and training some artificial neural networks from boilerplate code. I'm trying to solve an *exercise for newcomers* into the new tensorflow. I created some code, but it doesn't work. Below is the ***problem definition***:

---

Assuming we have tensor `M` of rational numbers in shape of `(a, b, c)` and scalar `p ∈ (0, 1)` (memory factor), let’s create a function that will return tensor `N` in shape of `(a, b, c)`. Each element of `N` tensors moving along axis *c* should be increased by the value of predecessor multiplied by `p`.

Assuming we have tensor:

```
T = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
```

in shape of `(1, 1, 4)`, we would like to get vector:

```
[x1, x2+x1·p, x3+(x2+x1·p)·p, x4+(x3+(x2+x1·p)·p)*p]
```

Solution should be created in *Tensorflow 2.0* and should be focused on delivering the shortest execution time on CPU. Created graph should allow to efficiently calculate derivative both on tensor `M` and value `p`.

---

This is the **code I created till now**:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def vectorize_predec(t, p):
    last_elem = 0
    result = []
    for el in t:
        result.append(el + (p * last_elem))
        last_elem = el + (p * last_elem)
    return result

p = tf.Variable(0.5, dtype='double')

m = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          [1, 3, 5, 7, 10],
          [1, 1, 1, -1, 0]])

vectorize_predec(m, p)
```

But it throws a `TypeError`.

I looked around documentation, I've seen functions like `cumsum` and `polyeval`, but I'm not sure they fit my needs. To my understanding, I need to write my own customer function annotated with `@tf.function`. I'm also not sure how to handle 3-dimension tensors properly according to the problem definition (adding the predecessor should happen on the last (*"c"*) axis).

I've seen in documentation (here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance) that there are ways to measure size of the produced graph. Although, I'm not sure how "graph" allows to efficiently calculate *derivative* both on tensor `M` and value `p`. ELI5 answers appreciated, or at least some materials I can read to educate myself better.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I've faced this exact problem, some time ago. I asked in CS.SE for advice about it, [Parallel or efficient computation of value with momentum](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/73746/70274), ended up doing something like what I mention there, a big matrix product that is more complex on paper, but ran way faster than using `tf.while_loop` or anything like that. I'll see if I can put something together...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give you a couple of different methods to implement that. I think the most obvious solution is to use [`tf.scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def apply_momentum_scan(m, p, axis=0):
    # Put axis first
    axis = tf.convert_to_tensor(axis, dtype=tf.int32)
    perm = tf.concat([[axis], tf.range(axis), tf.range(axis + 1, tf.rank(m))], axis=0)
    m_t = tf.transpose(m, perm)
    # Do computation
    res_t = tf.scan(lambda a, x: a * p + x, m_t)
    # Undo transpose
    perm_t = tf.concat([tf.range(1, axis + 1), [0], tf.range(axis + 1, tf.rank(m))], axis=0)
    return tf.transpose(res_t, perm_t)
```

However, you can also implement this as a particular matrix product, if you build a matrix of exponential factors:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, axis=0):
    # Put axis first and reshape
    m = tf.convert_to_tensor(m)
    p = tf.convert_to_tensor(p)
    axis = tf.convert_to_tensor(axis, dtype=tf.int32)
    perm = tf.concat([[axis], tf.range(axis), tf.range(axis + 1, tf.rank(m))], axis=0)
    m_t = tf.transpose(m, perm)
    shape_t = tf.shape(m_t)
    m_tr = tf.reshape(m_t, [shape_t[0], -1])
    # Build factors matrix
    r = tf.range(tf.shape(m_tr)[0])
    p_tr = tf.linalg.band_part(p ** tf.dtypes.cast(tf.expand_dims(r, 1) - r, p.dtype), -1, 0)
    # Do computation
    res_tr = p_tr @ m_tr
    # Reshape back and undo transpose
    res_t = tf.reshape(res_tr, shape_t)
    perm_t = tf.concat([tf.range(1, axis + 1), [0], tf.range(axis + 1, tf.rank(m))], axis=0)
    return tf.transpose(res_t, perm_t)
```

This can also be rewritten to avoid the first transposing (which in TensorFlow is expensive) with [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, axis=0):
    # Put axis first and reshape
    m = tf.convert_to_tensor(m)
    # Build factors matrix
    r = tf.range(tf.shape(m)[axis])
    p_mat = tf.linalg.band_part(p ** tf.dtypes.cast(tf.expand_dims(r, 1) - r, p.dtype), -1, 0)
    # Do computation
    res_t = tf.linalg.tensordot(m, p_mat, axes=[[axis], [1]])
    # Transpose
    last_dim = tf.rank(res_t) - 1
    perm_t = tf.concat([tf.range(axis), [last_dim], tf.range(axis, last_dim)], axis=0)
    return tf.transpose(res_t, perm_t)
```

The three functions would be used in a similar way:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

p = tf.Variable(0.5, dtype=tf.float32)
m = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [1, 3, 5, 7, 10],
                 [1, 1, 1, -1, 0]], tf.float32)
# apply_momentum is one of the functions above
print(apply_momentum(m, p, axis=0).numpy())
# [[ 0.    1.    2.    3.    4.  ]
#  [ 1.    3.5   6.    8.5  12.  ]
#  [ 1.5   2.75  4.    3.25  6.  ]]
print(apply_momentum(m, p, axis=1).numpy())
# [[ 0.      1.      2.5     4.25    6.125 ]
#  [ 1.      3.5     6.75   10.375  15.1875]
#  [ 1.      1.5     1.75   -0.125  -0.0625]]
```

Using a matrix product is more asymptotically complex, but it can be faster than scanning. Here is a small benchmark:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Make test data
tf.random.set_seed(0)
p = tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float32)
m = tf.random.uniform([100, 30, 50], dtype=tf.float32)

# Axis 0
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 0).numpy(), apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 0).numpy()))
# True
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 0).numpy(), apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 0).numpy()))
# True
%timeit apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 0)
# 11.5 ms ± 610 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 0)
# 1.36 ms ± 18.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 0)
# 1.62 ms ± 7.39 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Axis 1
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 1).numpy(), apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 1).numpy()))
# True
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 1).numpy(), apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 1).numpy()))
# True
%timeit apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 1)
# 4.27 ms ± 60.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 1)
# 1.27 ms ± 36.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 1)
# 1.2 ms ± 11.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# Axis 2
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 2).numpy(), apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 2).numpy()))
# True
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 2).numpy(), apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 2).numpy()))
# True
%timeit apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 2)
# 6.29 ms ± 64.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 2)
# 1.41 ms ± 21.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 2)
# 1.05 ms ± 26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So, matrix product seems to win. Let's see if this scales:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Make test data
tf.random.set_seed(0)
p = tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float32)
m = tf.random.uniform([1000, 300, 500], dtype=tf.float32)

# Axis 0
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 0).numpy(), apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 0).numpy()))
# True
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 0).numpy(), apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 0).numpy()))
# True
%timeit apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 0)
# 784 ms ± 6.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 0)
# 1.13 s ± 76.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 0)
# 1.3 s ± 27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Axis 1
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 1).numpy(), apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 1).numpy()))
# True
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 1).numpy(), apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 1).numpy()))
# True
%timeit apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 1)
# 852 ms ± 12.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 1)
# 659 ms ± 10.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 1)
# 741 ms ± 19.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Axis 2
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 2).numpy(), apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 2).numpy()))
# True
print(np.allclose(apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 2).numpy(), apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 2).numpy()))
# True
%timeit apply_momentum_scan(m, p, 2)
# 1.06 s ± 16.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit apply_momentum_matmul(m, p, 2)
# 924 ms ± 17 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit apply_momentum_tensordot(m, p, 2)
# 483 ms ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Well, now it's not so clear anymore. Scanning is still not super fast, but matrix products are sometimes slower. As you can imagine if you go to even bigger tensors the complexity of matrix products will dominate the timings.

So, if you want the fastest solution and know your tensors are not going to get huge, use one of the matrix product implementations. If you're fine with okay speed but want to make sure you don't run out of memory (matrix solution also takes much more) and timing is predictable, you can use the scanning solution.

Note: Benchmarks above were carried out on CPU, results may vary significantly on GPU.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that just provides some information, and a naive solution to fix the code---not the actual problem (please refer below for the why).

First of, the `TypeError` is a problem of incompatible types in the tensors of your early attempt. Some tensors contain floating point numbers (double), some contain integers. It would have helped to show the *full* error message:

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type int32 that does not match type float64 of argument 'x'.
```

Which happens to put on the right track (despite the gory details of the stack trace).

Here is a naive fix to get the code to work (with caveats against the target problem):

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function
def vectorize_predec(t, p):
    _p = tf.transpose(
        tf.convert_to_tensor(
            [p * t[...,idx] for idx in range(t.shape[-1] - 1)],
            dtype=tf.float64))
    _p = tf.concat([
        tf.zeroes((_p.shape[0], 1), dtype=tf.float64),
        _p
    ], axis=1)
    return t + _p

p = tf.Variable(0.5, dtype='double')

m = tf.constant([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
          [1, 3, 5, 7, 10],
          [1, 1, 1, -1, 0]], dtype=tf.float64)

n = tf.constant([[0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5],
          [1.0, 3.5, 6.5, 9.5, 13.5],
          [1.0, 1.5, 1.5, -0.5, -0.5]], dtype=tf.float64)
print(f'Expected: {n}')

result = vectorize_predec(m, p)
print(f'Result: {result}')

tf.test.TestCase().assertAllEqual(n, result)
```

The main changes:

- The `m` tensor gets a `dtype=tf.float64` to match the orignal `double`, so the type error vanishes.
- The function is basically a complete rewrite. The naive idea is to exploit the problem definition, which does *not* state whether the values in `N` are calculated before or after updates. Here is a version before update, way easier. Solving what seems to be the "real" problem requires working a bit more on the function (see other answers, and I may work more here).

How the function works:

- It calculates the expected increments `p * x1`, `p * x2`, etc into a standard Python array. Note it stops before the last element of the last dimension, as we will shift the array.
- It converts the array to a tensor with `tf.convert_to_tensor`, so adding the array to the computation graph. The transpose is necessary to match the original tensor shape (we could avoid it).
- It appends zeroes at the beginning of each dimension along the last axis.
- The result is the sum of the original tensor and the constructed one.

The values become `x1 + 0.0 * p`, then `x2 + x1 * p`, etc. This illustrates a few functions and issues to look at (types, shapes), but I admit it cheats and does not solve the actual problem.

Also, this code is not efficient on any hardware. It is just illustrative, and would need to (1) eliminate the Python array, (2) eliminate the transpose, (3) eliminate the concatenate operation. Hopefully great training :-)

---

Extra notes:

- The problem asks for a solution on tensors of shape (a, b, c). The code you share works on tensors of shape (a, b), so fixing the code will still not solve the problem.
- The problem requires rational numbers. Not sure what the intent
  is, and this answer leaves this requirement aside.
- The shape of `T = [x1, x2, x3, x4]` is actually `(4,)`, assuming `xi` are scalars.
- Why `tf.float64`? By default, we get `tf.float32`, and removing the `double` would make the code works. But the example would lose the point that types matter, so the choice for an explicit non-default type (and uglier code).